# visual basic 6 Error "Consumer Event Handler called a not reentrant method in the provider"

Tags: vb6

I am writing a login and new operator registration code in VB6 ADO.This are two different forms.First the user register if not then he login's.
I am getting a update problem while a need user registers.
The ERROR is "Consumer Event Handler called a not reentrant method in the provider"
I tried to google it but found no proper solution.
Here is the code for update subroutine.

```
  Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
   On Error GoTo errlabel
    If txtNewPassword.Text = txtConfirmPass.Text Then
       adorecordset.Update
       MsgBox "Record Updated Sucessfully"
    Else
       MsgBox "Password didnt match"
    End If
    Exit Sub
   errlabel:
     MsgBox Err.Description
  End Sub
```

Thankyou for the help.

Comment: [check this, seems related](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195638)

Comment: Thankyou can you please explain me what is client side cursor and server side cursor and how to change it?

Comment: [Client-Side Cursors Versus Server-Side Cursors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266531(v=vs.60).aspx) You specify the cursor location after you create the recordset as `Recordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient`

Comment: Did you try adding  `adorecordset.Move 0` , just before the `adorecordset.update` line, as shown in that link (Method B - Updating a Record)?

Comment: yes i tried adorecordset.Move 0 but now it give another error in the same line ERROR "Operation was canceled"

Comment: check this: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/database-and-reporting/322768-move-0-80040e4e-operation-canceled.html. Looks like you have to change the Cursor location

Comment: Thankyou Now everthing is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

From: [PRB: IRowsetNotify Error with ADO Data Control and ADO Recordset (OR "Consumer's event handler called a non-reentrant method in the provider" Error for Update)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195638)

> RESOLUTION
>
> 1.Use a [client-side cursor instead of a server-side cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266531(v=vs.60).aspx).
>
> -or-
>
> 2.Add a call to the Recordset's Move method immediately prior to the offending line. For example:
>
> ```
>   ADODC1.Recordset.Move 0
> ```
>
> -or-
>
> 3.Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 3 has been found to resolve this error in some scenarios.